# another input field appear when clicked on input field

Tags: javascript, html

I have this input field,

```
<div class="col-md-3">
  <strong>Field</strong>
  <input type="text" class="form-control load_field" name="field1">
  <br>
</div>
```

whenever clicked on this I want to make another field appear below this, I understand this will be done via 
EDIT:

I have done this,

```
    $(".load_field").click(function()
  {
    console.log("this");


       // document.getElementById('form').innerHTML+=getFormColumn(i);

      document.getElementById('form').innerHTML+="<div class='col-md-3'><strong>Field</strong> <input type='text' class='form-control load_field' name='field1'><br></div>";


    });
```

it works for the first time, means it shows another input field below this but only once, i want this to work every time input field is clicked. am i still missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what you want

```js
$(".load_field").click(function() {
  var html = '<input type="text" class="form-control load_field" name="field1"><br>';
  $(".col-md-3").append(html);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-3">
  <strong>Field</strong>
  <input type="text" class="form-control load_field" name="field1">
  <br>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with the following Code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".load_field").click(function(){
        $(".col-md-3").append('<input type="text" class="form-control load_field" name="field1"><br/><br/>');
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="col-md-3">
  <strong>Field</strong>
  <input type="text" class="form-control load_field" name="field1">
  <br>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here when you click on your text box. We will append the new Textbox in your div.

Answer (score 0):

***Try to put code block I didn't execute this code but the logic will remain same
Thanks***

```
  <div class="col-md-3">
      <strong>Field</strong>
      <input type="text" class="form-control load_field" name="field1">
    <div id="hidden" class="col-md-3" style="display:none;">
     <input type="text" class="form-control load_field" name="field1">
    </div>
      <br>
    </div>


    $(".load_field").click(function()

    {
    $("#hidden").display(visible);
     }
```

Comment: remove  load_field from hidden field

Answer (score 0):

Use Show / hide function to display or hide the html content.

```
<div class="col-md-3">
  <strong>Field</strong>
  <input type="text" class="form-control load_field" name="field1">
   //your new Field  
   <input type="text" class="form-control load_field" name="newField" id="newField" style="display:none">
  <br>
</div>
/*Your Js will look like */
$(".load_field").click(function()
$("#newField").show();
```